# DAL connection string for Web2Py to MySQL on TurnkeyLinux

Tags: mysql, web2py, turnkeylinux.org

On TurnkeyLinux I have tried to connect a Web2Py app to the MySQL instance (which is up and running) with the following DAL statement (in db.py):

db = DAL('mysql://root:pwd2sql@web2py/dbname', fake_migrate_all=True)

It doesn't work and throws the following ticket:

Failure to connect, tried 5 times: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/www/web2py/gluon/dal.py", line 7562, in init self.adapter = ADAPTERSself._dbname File "/var/www/web2py/gluon/dal.py", line 2572, in __init_ if do_connect: self.reconnect() File "/var/www/web2py/gluon/dal.py", line 606, in reconnect self.connection = f() File "/var/www/web2py/gluon/dal.py", line 2570, in connector return self.driver.connect(*driver_args) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/init.py", line 81, in Connect return Connection(args, *kwargs) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in init super(Connection, self).init(args, **kwargs2) OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'web2py' (111)")

Does anybody have a connection string sample I can use ?

Comment: is the database installed in the same server? in that case you can use something like "mysql://root:pwd2sql@localhost/dbname". By the way using root as DB user in app connection is not a very good idea

Comment: Thanks Cesar, the connection string mentioned is exactly what has eventually worked. What surprised me is the use of root and localhost in a production environment and also the fact that the hostname if one queries the MySQL about it -  it returns as 'web2py' and not localhost...Anyway now it works - thanks

Comment: As Cesar mentioned; don't use MySQL root user in production! FWIW in all the TurnKey appliances that include MySQL (other than the MySQL appliance itself) it is bound to localhost (for security). That's why your original command wouldn't work. There's nothing wrong with using localhost as a "name" for local connections, although be aware that sometimes unexpected results can occur if you have IPv6  configured (if services are only listening on IPv4).